# Handle errors passing wrong date format for cxf

Tags: java, json, rest, cxf

I'm using cxf server for rest webservice providing a jackson provider with SimpleDateFormat as date format
as described here

[How do I configure the date format the server returns using CXF JAX-RS and Jackson 2 in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508917/how-do-i-configure-the-date-format-the-server-returns-using-cxf-jax-rs-and-jacks)

It works providing a date time.format as defined for it rather it produce a server error.

The goal is to convert received date and convert it or return a description error to the client

Following xml configurations

```
<bean id="dataFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value=" yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" />
</bean>


<bean id="jaxbAnnIntrospector" class="org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector" />

<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationConfig.annotationIntrospector"
            ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
    <property name="deserializationConfig.annotationIntrospector"
            ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
    <property name="dateFormat" ref="dataFormat" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider">
    <property name="mapper" ref="objectMapper" />
</bean>

<jaxrs:providers>
            ...
    <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            ...
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Server Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
    at javax.ws.rs.ServerErrorException.<init>(ServerErrorException.java:101)
    at javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.<init>(InternalServerErrorException.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post the code that "provides a date time.format as defined for it rather it produce a server error"

Comment: updated post @IvanPronin

Answer (score 0):

This error most likely points to some Java versions / jar / classpath contents issue. So, issue is not in Date formatting itself, but in your project set up.

It's diffcult to directly say what causes it, but I suggest using a general troubleshooting guide for this kind of issue: [How do I fix a NoSuchMethodError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186/how-do-i-fix-a-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: Sorry but it's a no such method due to an invalid a Dto for that Date field..so it fails before perform rest method as cxf exeptions... passing a correct format it works...

Comment: No, this error tells that JVM cannot find a method to handle appropriate task. For incorrect dateTime format Exception class would be different, e.g. `ParseException`